# Download image from server and set it to Imageview for different density devices in Android

Tags: android

I used the following to download and an image from server and tried to set to an `imageview`, for `mdpi` device the image size is fine, for `ldpi` it is larger, and for `hdpi` and `xhdpi` it is smaller.

Can any one help me to set the right parameters for setting it same for all the devices?

```
in = OpenHttpConnection(strURL); //input stream from server...

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
int currDensity = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;

options.inDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM;
switch(currDensity) 
{
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
        options.inDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW;
        options.inTargetDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW; 
        break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
        options.inDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM;
        options.inTargetDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW;
        break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
        options.inDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH;
         options.inTargetDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH;
        break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
        options.inDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH;
        options.inTargetDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH;
        break;
}

 /
options.inScaled = true;
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in,null,options);
in.close();
```

I tried setting different options for Bitmap options but none of them worked for `hdpi` and `xhdpi`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use image downloading & rendering libraries like [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) & [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)